# django rest framework token authorization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm doing tutorial and I have a problem with access to data with authorization token.
I changed in my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
```

I generate users and tokens for them, if I try GET, response is

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: e7e9047a515b141209ace33597b53771ef8f5483'
```

i used commad: `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'` from https://riptutorial.com/django-rest-framework/example/28222/using-curl of course with my token and address

[image]

If I change `'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'` to `'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'`
and use `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/friends/`there are no problems, I'm getting json form database. I don't know what i'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',  # <-- Here
    ....
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

to get a token you may run this command

`python manage.py drf_create_token username`

For more details, refer to [this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html)

Comment: In INSTALLED_APPS I had this, if i change REST_FRAMEWORK i don't have to provide token and I get the result from the database. I created token for user.

Comment: you still need the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in REST_FRAMEWORK, just add the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES which handles the tokens

Comment: Thanks, I haven't changed anything since yesterday, I tried today and everything works, and yesterday it didn't work, the same commands...